# Setting Alarm on 9 AM GMT

Tags: android, timezone, alarmmanager, gmt

I'm having a strange problem. I need to set a task to run exactly at 9 AM GMT. Here's the code I'm using:

```
AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone
                    .getTimeZone("GMT"));
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);

            mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
```

My timezone is GMT+2. As a test I've tried to set alarm at this time:

```
Alarm time = My time - 2 hours + couple of minutes to catch the alarm
```

But it never worked. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be the problem:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);
```

That's setting the "hour of the morning or afternoon" - do if you're already in the afternoon, it'll set it to 9pm. I think you want:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
```

It's possible that that doesn't explain your problem, but it's certainly *one* thing to fix. Note that it will be on the same day - so if you do this after 9am, it's not going to fire.

(You should probably set the seconds field to 0, too.)

Comment: I've tried setting HOUR to 13, since it's now 15 in my timezone. Unfortunately this doesn't work..

Comment: @Egor: HOUR shouldn't be 13 or 15 - it should be 1 or 3. HOUR_OF_DAY would be 13 or 15.